# Line number in file

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having some problem with getting line number.

Here is what I got :

```
        var lines = File.ReadLines(fileNameData, Encoding.Default);

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains("()"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(line );
            }
        }
```

Which show me

```
       MessageBox.Show(line );
```

So it's shows me lanes which contains (), and it works correctly.
Is there any possibitity to get this line number.

```
       MessageBox.Show(line + lineIndex);
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish that?

Comment: use a counter variable.

Comment: Declare a integer outside the for loop, then increment it each loop, eg: int i=0;  and i++;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    var lines = File.ReadLines(fileNameData, Encoding.Default);  
    int lineIndex=0;

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (line.Contains("()"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(line + lineIndex);
        }
        lineIndex++;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, it works :)

Comment: In your rush to answer, you forgot to make sure your post was formatted correctly.

Comment: I just formatted :)

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is add an interger variable and increment this value for each line that you 'traverse'. Eg.

int counter = 0;

and then in the foreach loop

counter++;